# How to plot time values in Flot Graph

Tags: javascript, flot

I am using [Flot Graph Api](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) to plot graphs, I want to plot time values in bar charts.

My table look like some thing similar to this

[image]

My X-Axis should be list of Reasons and Y-Axis should be time variables. My Graph should be some thing like this.

[image]

but i get something like this, because of the Json object is packed wrongly.

[image]

How to plot graph for time values in

My plot JS code is

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('ReasonByTime.txt', function(json) {
   //succes - data loaded, now use plot:
       var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
       var dataBar=json.data;
        $.plot(plotarea , [
            {
                data: dataBar,
                bars: { show: true},
                legend: {show: true},
                yaxis: {
                    mode: 'time',
                    timeformat: "%y/%m/%d",
                        min: ( new Date('2012/01/01') ).getTime(),
                        max: ( new Date('2020/01/01') ).getTime(), 
                        minTickSize: [1, 'hour']
                }
            }          
        ]
    );
});
```

});

and my current Json object is like this.

```
  {"data":[[0,5202],[0,19620],[0,82920],[0,240],[0,75720],[0,3060],[0,72840]],"label":"Tea break"}
```

Since i'm new to flot i'm struck up with this work, i did some research but i can't able to solve my problem. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DNS, the problem is the all my x-axis values are zero, so i changed my JSON in the following format,

```
  [{"data":[[0,5202]],"label":"Over Time"},{"data":[[1,19620]],"label":"Shift Start"},{"data":[[2,82920]],"label":"Maintenance break"},{"data":[[3,240]],"label":"Lunch break"},{"data":[[4,75720]],"label":"BreakDown"},{"data":[[5,3060]],"label":"Break"},{"data":[[6,72840]],"label":"Tea break"},{"data":[[6,79260]],"label":"Power Failure"}]
```

Now i get my graph like this,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the JSON, but with your data itself.  Your x-axis values are all zero, so Flot is correctly plotting all the bars on top of one another.

Comment: Thanks DNS, i fixed the bug, its working now. I want to use Ticks to display reason in the x-axis, but when i add the tickets with the Json and tried to use it, it was not working for me. How can i use Ticks.

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question, but take a look at the [categories plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.categories.js)

Comment: Thanks DNS, I have modified my JSON like the example data format in Categories, but my x-axis is not even displaying even default values. Hence i take your advice and post as a New question, which might be usefull to someone in future.

Comment: i have posted as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506586/how-to-add-dynamics-ticks-through-json-in-flot