# How to add Dynamics Ticks through JSON in Flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want to change the X-Axis values from default to Dynamic Ticks which is passed from JSON.

Through my last post [How to plot time values in Flot Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490667/how-to-plot-time-values-in-flot-graph/13496103#comment18485567_13496103), I found out that it is possible through [Categories.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.categories.js)

I added the JS and modified My JSON in the format below matching to the format given in the Example.

```
  [{"data":[["Over Time",5202]],"label":"Over Time"},{"data":[["Shift Start",19620]],"label":"Shift Start"},{"data":[["Maintenance break",82920]],"label":"Maintenance break"},{"data":[["Lunch break",240]],"label":"Lunch break"},{"data":[["BreakDown",75720]],"label":"BreakDown"},{"data":[["Break",3060]],"label":"Break"},{"data":[["Tea break",72840]],"label":"Tea break"}]
```

and my JS code as

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('ReasonByTime.txt', function(json) {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"),json, {bars: { show: true, barWidth:0.2}, xaxis: { mode: "categories" }});
});
```

});

When i run this code, x-axis is not displaying any values, the default values also not getting displayed. My result graph is look like this.

[image]

I tested The sample example given in [code.google.com/p/flot/](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/examples/categories.html?r=341&spec=svn341) but the tickes/categories is not working. I get the Output for the example like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot is now hosted out of github:  https://github.com/flot/flot

If you grab [jquery.flot.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.js) and [jquery.flot.categories.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.categories.js) from there and run your code, it will work.  What does **NOT** work is jquery.flot.js version 0.7 combined with the latest categories plugin from github.

I ran it with this code and it displayed correctly:

```
var data = [{
    "data": [["Over Time", 5202]]},
{
    "data": [["Shift Start", 19620]]},
{
    "data": [["Maintenance break", 82920]]},
{
    "data": [["Lunch break", 240]]},
{
    "data": [["BreakDown", 75720]]},
{
    "data": [["Break", 3060]]},
{
    "data": [["Tea break", 72840]]}];


$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.2
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories"
    }
});​
```

Here is a working version of it:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/CQ3YS/

Comment: i have a dount, How to access the ticks created in JSON inside plot JS. also due to more number of entries in my x-axis, the categories displayed at the bottom of the x-axis are overlapping each other. can you help me to fix this problem.